# Help in ActiveRecord find with include on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, has-many

I have a `Coach` Model which:

```
has_many :qualifications
```

I want to find all coaches whose some `attribute_id` is `nil` and they have some `qualifications`. Something which is like.

```
def requirement
    legal_coaches = []
    coaches = find_all_by_attribute_id(nil)
    coaches.each do |coach|
        legal_coaches << coach if coach.qualifications.any?
    end
    legal_coaches
end
```

Is there a way to get all such records in one line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find_all_by_attribute_id(nil).select(&:qualification)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that via purely ruby syntax. I can only think of the following (ugly) way

```
Coach.find(:all, :conditions => "attribute_id IS NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM qualifications WHERE coach_id = coaches.id)")
```